# mysqli query returning metadata instead of fields

Tags: php, sql, session, mysqli

This mysqli query returns the metadata for the given column, instead of the data in the column:

```
$query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT id FROM users WHERE pword = '$codeword'");

//Start user session
if ($query) {
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['login'] = true;
    $_SESSION['codeword'] = $codeword;
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
    $id = $row['id'];
    $_SESSION['id'] = $id;

// Send user to launchpad
    header("Location: menu.php");
    exit;
} else {
    echo "Error!";
}
```

IE when I do this:

```
var_dump($_SESSION['id']);
```

It returns this:

```
        object(stdClass)#1 (13) {
  ["name"]=>
  string(2) "id"
  ["orgname"]=>
  string(2) "id"
  ["table"]=>
  string(5) "users"
  ["orgtable"]=>
  string(5) "users"
  ["def"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["db"]=>
  string(4) "game"
  ["catalog"]=>
  string(3) "def"
  ["max_length"]=>
  int(1)
  ["length"]=>
  int(50)
  ["charsetnr"]=>
  int(63)
  ["flags"]=>
  int(32768)
  ["type"]=>
  int(3)
  ["decimals"]=>
  int(0)
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Aaaand it's telling me to add text so here we go.

EDIT: Still doing the same thing after I changed the code to

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    $id = $row['id'];
}
$_SESSION['id'] = $id;
```

EDIT #2: I'm trying to get the text value from field 'id' in the 'game' database. I have code in my other register.php file which does this alright, it looks like this:

```
$query1 = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT id FROM users WHERE id = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM users);");
$column = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query1);
$id = $column["id"];
$id = $id + 1;
```

But when I try the same thing, slightly differently for this file:

```
$query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE pword = '$codeword'");
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
$id = $row["id"];
$_SESSION['id'] = $id;
```

And try to access it as text:

```
echo $_SESSION['id'];
```

It gives me the error 'Catchable fatal error:  Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string in /opt/lampp/htdocs/Game/index.php on line 12'

Comment: is `$codeword` a string?

Comment: Yes. But it does the same thing if I put it inside quotes fyi

Comment: Just forgot to put it back into quotes in my post, brb

Comment: you have no choice *but* to wrap it in quotes. Do that, run the code again and then write in your question what that error is

Comment: you didn't fetch anything from the query, that's why.

Comment: How exactly would I fetch something? I've tried a couple of ways

Comment: Ok, I don't know what you're asking here. That is perfectly normal. what are you trying to do and what is the real question/problem?

Comment: I'll add an edit with more details.

Comment: well somebody else gave you an answer, see that.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

EDIT: Got it working! Dunno if anyone will be back, but here's what worked:

```
$query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE pword = '$codeword'");
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
$_SESSION['id'] = $row['id'];
```

Answer (score 0):

> *when I do this:
>   var_dump($_SESSION['id']);
>   It returns this:*

- Which is normal.

You need to loop over from your query if you want to echo those out.

Use a loop of sorts, such as `while($row)` or a `foreach`.

Read the docs:

- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php

this assuming you have connected with the same API, being `mysqli_` and not any other.

I.e.:

`while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){...}`

and check for errors on the query:

- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php

and via php:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: @Nienaber You're welcome. If I don't hear from you again, then you could mark the question as solved *lol*.

Comment: @Nienaber, don't just say Thanks and run away ... accept it if it helped you.

Comment: dv'er, care to share your wisdom?

Comment: I'll of course accept as soon as I get it figured out, thanks for the roast.

Answer (score -1):

*Of course*, "mysqli_query" **doesn't return anything like this**.

Neither the code you posted would ever have such an outcome. It means that your `$_SESSION['id']` variable **gets overwritten somewhere else.**

You can test it by var_dump'ing the returned id **right in place**, before any redirects.

Comment: A var_dump($id) returns nothing.

Comment: Also @Fred -ii- you said I didn't fetch anything, but I grabbed an associative array and then the 'id' field from within it (or tried to). Am I not doing this correctly?